# Replace item.title in yahoo pipes with regex

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

In Yahoo Pipes, titles of feed'items :

- some words 23 january 2012 some words
- some words 3 february 2012 some words
- some words 04 july 2012 some words

I want to replace them by

- 23 january 2012
- 3 february 2012
- 04 july 2012

I use regex

replace item.title ^.+(\d{1,2}.+\d{4}) with $1

But i obtain

- 3 january 2012
- 3 february 2012
- 4 july 2012

I have no idea to solve my problem.
If someone could help me.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your first .+ is grabbing the first digit, because your capturing rule, \d{1,2} says grab 1 or two digits, and .+ can grab anything.  Be more specific and put a \s+ before matching the digits.

Why not try:

```
.+\s+(\d{1,2}\s+\S+\s+\d{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to simplify your regex, for example `\d{1,2}.+\d{4}`